# Merge CSS and Less with webpack

Tags: css, webpack, less

How can I merge CSS and LESS through webpack and which additional node modules do I need?

Do I need two different entry-files, one for LESS and one for CSS? If so, what is the best way to do this?

Problems arise when importing .css files within a .less file.

**CSS**

```
test: /\.css$/,
exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/],
  use: [
    {
      loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      options: {}
    },
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      }
    },
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        plugins: [
          autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['>2%', 'last 4 versions', 'Firefox ESR', 'not ie < 9']
          }),
          postcssPresetEnv(),
          PostcssClean({
            sourceMap: true,
            level: 1
          })
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

**LESS**

```
test: /\.less$/,
exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/],
use: [
  MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
  {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      sourceMap: true
    }
  },
  {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
      sourceMap: true,
      plugins: [
        autoprefixer({
          browsers: ['>2%', 'last 4 versions', 'Firefox ESR', 'not ie < 9']
        }),
        postcssPresetEnv(),
        PostcssClean({
          sourceMap: true,
          level: 1
        })
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    loader: 'less-loader',
   options: {
     sourceMap: true
   }
 }
]
```

### EDIT

The solution is to define two different entry points and then process CSS and LESS separately from each other.

With the SASS loader, @Pete's (look in the comments) solution seems to be the best. Simply let CSS and SASS be processed by the same loader.

Comment: can you not just change the css files to less? Or do something like 
`test: /\.(css|less)$/,`

Comment: @Pete hehe, clever idea but I've already found the solution. You need, very simple, two different entry files and everything works. So you have to handle CSS and LESS separately from each other. Applies to autoprefixer etc.

`test: /\.(css|less)$/,` leads to an error, because the less-loader then tries to process css

Comment: weird - we use sass and are able to process both sass and css using this config: https://jsfiddle.net/por18h4x/